# "PowerShell Script Workflow Action"(approve/reject) is not fired from the workbox page on IE browser

Tags: powershell-extensions, workbox

"PowerShell Script Workflow Action"(approve/reject) is not fired from the workbox page on IE browser.

Whereas it is working fine on chrome browser.

None of the buttons(approve,approval all, reject etc) fires the PowerShell Script Workflow Action[image]

Comment: Which Sitecore and IE version you are on?

Comment: I am using Sitecore 8.2 update 4 and IE edge and below.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the workflow as well? I just tested 4.7 in IE 11 and it worked.